# View the original price, the discounted price and the discount percentage

Tags: commerce

I am currently working on a newsletter and I want to display the prices of my products there. How to recover the original price, discounted prices and the discount percentage. I wish to put three different value to place my letter and apply a different style.

With this line **`print render($content['product:commerce_price']);`**
it displays the three values. But I would separate them.

So what line of code do I type to get the original price, then to get the discounted price and then to get the discount percentage?
here is a product page of my site [enter link description here](http://www.s1biose.com/boutique/produit/savon-d-alep-artisanal-bio-5-de-laurier)

thank you

Comment: I need to separate the three, to display prices in simplenews

Comment: there is no solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is Drupal 7, you can use the [Commerce Price Savings Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter).  This extends the price field to show the "list price" and "sale price" and automatically calculates the percentage.

The module page links to a [video explaining how to use the module](https://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-price-savings-formatter).